# C++ read a Registry entry in SOFTWARE\WOW6432 from a 64-bit app

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I've got some 32-bit C++ code to read a Key/Value pair from the Registry as follows:

```
    // Get a handle to the required key
    HKEY    hKey;
    if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\MyKey", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        // Look up the value for the key
        bOK = (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, szKey, NULL, NULL, (PBYTE)szValue, &dwMax) == ERROR_SUCCESS);
        
        // Release the handle
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
```

As it's a 32-bit app it reads from  SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\MyKey

This was working fine until I ported the app to 64-bit, so it now reads  from SOFTWARE\MyKey.

My installer won't let me put entries into both the 32-bit and 64-bit parts of the Registry, so I need the 64-bit app to go on  getting its data from WOW6432Node.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Many thanks
Tony Reynolds

Comment: So you have a single installer for the 32-Bit and the 64-Bit version of your software? That sounds unusual.

Comment: I use Advanced Installer which is a front-end for MSI. It has a 32/64 bit build mode.

Answer (score 5):

As documented under [32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/32-bit-and-64-bit-application-data-in-the-registry):

> The KEY_WOW64_64KEY and KEY_WOW64_32KEY flags enable explicit access to the 64-bit registry view and the 32-bit view, respectively. For more information, see [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view).

The latter link explains that

> These flags can be specified in the *samDesire*d parameter of the following registry functions:
>
> - [RegCreateKeyEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regcreatekeyexa)
> - [RegDeleteKeyEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regdeletekeyexa)
> - [RegOpenKeyEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexa)

The following code accomplishes what you are asking for:

```cpp
// Get a handle to the required key
HKEY    hKey;
if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\MyKey", 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    // ...
}
```